# Efficient intersection operation between non-disjoint sets

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, time-complexity, memoization, set-intersection

Does anybody knows of specific data-structures/algorithm to handle the following problem efficiently:

Given a set `A` and a set of sets `S = {X,Y,Z..}` I want to compute the size of the intersection between A and all sets in S exploiting the fact that most of them are non-disjoint i.e. share numbers.

For example: given `A = {1,2...10}`, `X = {1,3,4,5,7}` and `Y = {2,4,5,7,9,10}`, it's more efficient to compute the intersection between `A` and `X intersect Y`, `A` and `X - X intersect Y`, `A` and `Y - X intersect Y` and the sum up the results.

A practical example could be finding the number of occurrences of a keyword in a large set of documents that shares piece of text, (not the total, but per-document.)

Note that the only difference to Map-Reduce is that documents share parts of texts, and those parts should be parsed only once.

If this can be of any help, the way I am reasoning about the problem right now is of a graph/tree in which nodes are overlapping regions whose `O(n)` traversal gives the size of intersection between A and all elements of S. The problem I am facing is how to find the optimal set of nodes to be used. But maybe there are already off-the-shelf solutions for it.

Comment: What's wrong with testing each element in X,Y,Z,... if it is contained in A? I think your "set abstraction" does not show the relevant conditions of your actual problem.

Comment: It's not efficient. I can reduce the number of operation to compute the intersection exploiting the fact that most of the set are non-disjoint.

Comment: With `N = |X| + |Y| + |Z| + ...` the effort of iterating over the elements in X,Y,Z, ... is `O(N)`. When A is stored as a balanced tree, then checking if an element is in A is `O(log(|A|))`. So the total complexity of the straight forward checking is `O(N)*O(log(|A|))`. Where is the inefficiency here that you want to improve? Or why should your approach be faster?

Comment: If I exploit overlaps I might be able to have complexity `O(M)*O(log(|A|))` where `M = |O1| + |O2| + |O3| ... + |X-O1-O2-O3| + |Y-O1-O2-O3| + ...` which for highly overlapping sets yield `M << N`, and this is the part I want to make more efficient. Best possible case is M = `|X U Y U Z U ...|`

Comment: Sure, if you have `X u Y u Z u ...` then use it. But if you only have `X, Y, Z, ...` then you need to generate the union first - again with `O(N)`. This will only pay off, if you have several sets A, with which you want to intersect.

Comment: Yes, the number of sets A is huge, so I have good reasons to search for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect big overlaps then it might be worth storing the sets as treaps with unique representation of nodes. This should be faster than anything else if the overlaps are big enough.

See the following answer:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18006/10483